# Cut off point with three categories

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I have a categorical variable called severity with three categories (low, medium, high) and another numerical variable call ZX that can take values from 0 to 10. I want to find the cut off points of the numerical variable in order to determine three categories (also low, medium and high) that maximize the agreement of both variables. By agreement I mean the percentage of values that coincide in the same category in both variables after the definition of the cut off point. Any idea about how to do it?

Some data as an example are as follows:

```
ZX          Severity
2.818181818 high
2.084242424 high
5.326666667 medium
4.758484848 low
4.795454545 high
3.367878788 high
5.734848485 high
3.417575758 medium
3.16000     medium
4.307272727 low
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "variable" and "agreement," because both these terms have many different (but related) meanings in statistics and you haven't provided enough context to help your readers determine what you're asking about.